# How to break text at specific word in an HTML table cell?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I've seen many examples using `style='"white-space:pre-wrap; word-wrap:break-word";` for example, but I didn't see how to break the text into multiple lines breaking at specific words.

So, [this Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/santosonit/ch5zkty0/6/#&togetherjs=lJVoIK1TvT) currently displays:

```
First Name/Appartment, No.137, Joseph South Road, Sec. 2, Fortaleza, Country Tel: +55-8-1234567 email@email.com; email2@email2.com
```

but it should look like:

```
First Name/Appartment, No.137, 
Joseph South Road, Sec. 2, Fortaleza, Country 
Tel: +55-8-1234567 
email@email.com; email2@email2.com
```

Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way that `white-space:pre-wrap;` can wrap the line as you intended without any indications. Consider manually adding line breaks in your code and use `white-space:pre-line;` to preserve the breaks:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class='address' style="white-space: pre-line;">First Name/Appartment, No.137, 
    Joseph South Road, Sec. 2, Fortaleza, Country 
    Tel: +55-8-1234567 
    email@email.com; email2@email2.com
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

The [line break element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/br) `<br>` works pretty good for this.

```css
p {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<p>First Name/Appartment, No.137,<br>
Joseph South Road, Sec. 2, Fortaleza, Countr<br>
Tel: +55-8-123456<br>
email@email.com; email2@email2.com<br>
</p>
```

`-webkit-user-modify: read-write-plaintext-only;` will print the text the same way it is in the markup.

```css
p {
  -webkit-user-modify: read-write-plaintext-only;
}
```

```html
<p>First Name/Appartment, No.137,
Joseph South Road, Sec. 2, Fortaleza, Countr
Tel: +55-8-123456
email@email.com; email2@email2.com
</p>
```

⚠️  [`user-modify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/user-modify) is a deprecated feature

Answer (score 1):

CSS Cares about document structure, not content, so you can't do what you want with *just* css.

You have a semantic structure to your html, use it. This way you can style each logical element as needed.

```css
.name, .apptNum {display:inline-block;}
.name::after {content:'/';}
.apptNum::after {content: ',';}
.address, .tel, .email {display: block;}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
     <span class="name">First Name</span>
     <span class="apptNum">Appartment, No.137</span> 
     <span class="address">Joseph South Road, Sec. 2, Fortaleza, Country</span>
     <span class="tel">Tel: +55-8-1234567</span>
     <span class="email">email@email.com; email2@email2.com</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```